# React: Child Prop inside Map Function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Parent component initialized like so:

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      children: [
        {name: "Julien Lennon"},
        {name: "Sean Lennon"}
      ]
    }
  }
  render() {
    return <div class="parent">Parent, called {this.props.name}
        {this.state.children.map((child, index) => {
          return (
            <Child name="{child.name}" />
          );
        })}
    </div>;
  }
}
```

Now, in the child I just want to access the name prop:

```
class Child extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div class="child">Child named {this.props.name}</div>;
  }
}
```

But its outputing the name as a literal: Child named {child.name}

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/89k1zcdp/6/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this rather

```
<Child name={child.name} />
```

Comment: Thanks, you beat the other answer by 30 seconds! I'll accept when I can.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to remove the quotes around {child.name} in your Parent component's render function. 
Like this:

```
<Child name={child.name} />
```

**Explanation:**
In React, the HTML-like code is actually React's own templating language called JSX. In JSX, you can indicate that a section of code is meant to be interpreted as JavaScript by wrapping it in brackets: {}. But since `"{child.name}"` is wrapped in those double quotes it turns the brackets and everything they contain into a string. Removing the quotes like so `{child.name}` will reference the name property of the child object like you would expect JS to do.

Comment: You are the MAN!

Comment: Hi @jared, welcome to StackOverflow! Can you explain _why_ removing the quotes around `{child.name}` works?

Comment: @IvanGarcíaTopete, added that to my answer for you ;).